# Duvida sobre laravel; Como ele executa esse código?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou aprendendo sobre `Laravel` e fiquei intrigado para saber como funciona uma parte do código do `framework` referente a `Seeder` e a duvida é sobre o código a seguir:

```
public function run() 
{    
   Categoria::insert(['nome'=>'Dúvidas','descricao'=>'Tire suas dúvidas agora mesmo!']);
   Categoria::insert(['nome'=>'Sugestões','descricao'=>'Gostaria de sugerir algo?']);
   Categoria::insert(['nome'=>'Outros','descricao'=>'Qualquer outro tipo de assunto']);
}
```

Como e onde o `Laravel` redireciona a execução desse código?

Sobre o que conheço de `PHP`, isso é uma chamada de uma função estática na classe `Categoria`, mas não há nenhum método `insert` nessa classe.

Se tiverem dicas de site e livros sobre o `Laravel` será de boa ajuda(*preferência em PT*).

Comment: A classe `Categoria` tem algo como **`extends Model`**, certo?

Comment: Sim, esse classe tem um extends Model.

Comment: O método pode estar nesta classe =)

Comment: não há nenhum metodo neste lugar com esse nome.

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função que você procura está dentro da classe **Builder** (vendor/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder/Builder.php), é difícil encontrar algo além das definições da documentação, se você quiser desmembrar cada função do framework vai ter que procurar nos arquivos, que por sorte estão comentados.

**Função insert da classe Builder.php** (Laravel versão 5.5)

```
   /**
     * Insert a new record into the database.
     *
     * @param  array  $values
     * @return bool
     */
    public function insert(array $values)
    {
        // Since every insert gets treated like a batch insert, we will make sure the
        // bindings are structured in a way that is convenient when building these
        // inserts statements by verifying these elements are actually an array.
        if (empty($values)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (! is_array(reset($values))) {
            $values = [$values];
        }

        // Here, we will sort the insert keys for every record so that each insert is
        // in the same order for the record. We need to make sure this is the case
        // so there are not any errors or problems when inserting these records.
        else {
            foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                ksort($value);

                $values[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        // Finally, we will run this query against the database connection and return
        // the results. We will need to also flatten these bindings before running
        // the query so they are all in one huge, flattened array for execution.
        return $this->connection->insert(
            $this->grammar->compileInsert($this, $values),
            $this->cleanBindings(Arr::flatten($values, 1))
        );
    }
```